# Android WebView UserAgent

Tags: android, webview, user-agent

is it possible to change UserAgent which depends on a specific URL ? Something like this.

```
    String url = webView.getUrl();
    String userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    if (url.contains("website") && userAgent.contains(" Mobile Safari")) {
        int index = userAgent.indexOf(" Mobile Safari");
        if (index != -1) {
            String fixedUserAgent = userAgent.substring(0, index);
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(fixedUserAgent);
        }
    } else {
        if (!userAgent.contains("MyBrowser")) {
            String fixedUserAgent = userAgent + " Mobile Safari/537.36 MyBrowser/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + "a";
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(fixedUserAgent);
        }
    }
```

But I do not know where I should put this code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in that part of onLoadResource or PageStarted and add webview.LoadUrl(youtURLs) Like this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
 if (url.contains("website") && userAgent.contains(" Mobile Safari")) {
        int index = userAgent.indexOf(" Mobile Safari");
        if (index != -1) {
            String fixedUserAgent = userAgent.substring(0, index);
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(fixedUserAgent);
    webview.LoadUrl(youtURLs)
        }
    } else {
        if (!userAgent.contains("MyBrowser")) {
            String fixedUserAgent = userAgent + " Mobile Safari/537.36 MyBrowser/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + "a";
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(fixedUserAgent);
    webview.LoadUrl(youtURLs)

        }
    }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
    });
```